# how to use file's contents as script input

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

say i have a script called myscript and it takes two arguments and should be run as the following:

```
./myscript 1st 2nd
```

I also have a text file like this:

```
213 432
312 54
34 41
1 32
```

The question is that how can I run myscript using the content of the text file as my input?

The input redirection should result in running exactly the same as the following:

```
./myscript 213 432
./myscript 312 54
./myscript 34 41
./myscript 1 32
```

Thank you.

And what if i dont know the number of arguments needed by my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `while read` to read lines from the text file separated with $IFS into two variables and call myscript with it:

```
while read -r A B; do
    ./myscript "$A" "$B"
done < text_file
```

To have every line passed as a whole single argument:

```
while read -r A; do
    ./myscript "$A"
done < text_file
```

To have each token of every line passed as arguments:

```
while read -ra A; do
    ./myscript "${A[@]}"
done < text_file
```

Comment: Thank you. what if i dont know the number of arguments needed by my script?

Comment: @user2565858 There's no way to know that programmatically.

Comment: @user2565858 then use arrays: `while read -a ary; do ./myscript "${ary[@]}"; done < text_file`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I was about to edit my code when I realized it was actually the script itself that he wanted to know how many arguments are required.

Comment: @user2565858 If your scripts don't mind having any number of arguments and that you could just send in the data, you can have gniourf_gniourf's concept.

Comment: my script don't mind having any number of arguments and all i need is just to take each line of the txtfile as its arguments

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have to preserve any spaces in the arguments, you can manage an indefinite number of arguments using:

```
while read -r line
do ./myscript $line
done < text_file
```

If you must preserve spaces, interpret quotes, etc, then the best bet is probably:

```
sed 's%^%./myscript %' text_file | bash
```

This inserts the command at the start of each line in the file and then runs the script through `bash`.